# Swapping two 2D Arrays of integers

Tags: java, arrays, swap

I am looking to completely swap the contents of two arrays, not swap integers within the array, but across the two. I am just very confused as to where to begin.

ie...

```
Matrix a = 1 2 3   Matrix b = 3 2 1
           4 5 6              6 5 4
```

I wish for it to output as

```
Matrix a = 3 2 1   Matrix b = 1 2 3
           6 5 4              4 5 6
```

If that makes sense. Sorry! My code is below for the beginning part of creating the array and filling it with Random, I didn't include the tester because I'm simply inputting which array to use for the calculation, and I am not ready to do that yet.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Matrix {
private int[][] matrix;
private int rows;

//constructors
public Matrix() {
    matrix = new int[3][3];
    rows = 3;
}

public Matrix(int size) {
    matrix = new int[size][size];
    rows = size;
}

//Mutators
public void fill() {
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.rows; j++) {
            this.matrix[i][j] = r.nextInt();
        }
    }
}

public void clear() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.rows; j++) {
            this.matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

public static void swap(Matrix a, Matrix B) {

}

}
```

Comment: First problem: your code uses square matrices, when your demo isn't square. Fix that. For the swapping itself, use a temporary array with size equal to the number of rows you have. Then you can do: `temp = a; a = b; b = temp;`

Comment: Can you have temporary variables? (The case unless this is a (imo silly) excercise where that is forbidden)

Comment: Yes temp variables are fine, it was actually much more simple than I had expected I was thinking in the line of some crazy loop that swaps the elements one by one. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply swap the `matrix` fields:

```
public static void swap(Matrix a, Matrix b) {
    int[][] tmp = a.matrix;
    a.matrix = b.matrix;
    b.matrix = tmp;
}
```

You should probably first check that the matrices have the same size. Alternatively, also swap the value of the `rows` field between `a` and `b`.

Comment: I was looking much too far into the pseudo-code and thought that I would need to loop through and change every element thank you. I just used try/catch and threw an error if they didn't match.